# Is an Windows 8.1 Emergency App for Windows Store doable?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

At my current level of knowledge, I think it is not possible, to develop an emergency or time critical alarm app for Windows 8.1 as a Windows Store App (no Desktop).
Maybe also Windows Phone 8 would fit such app scenario, for having smaller devices to carry around.

For (fictitious) example you have a blind person walking down a road, now he or she unfortunately enters a area, where no one should walk around without seeing something, then the app should warn the person with a toast notification (with sound or vibration) or some UI related function if the app is on top but the Screen is turned off.

As Windows 8.1 sets time limits to the background tasks to safe battery life, I think it is not possible to build such an app on that plattform.
A similar scenario is this question [Location tracking windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14259446/3111930), but it was Windows 8 he asks about and now it is 1 year over and I hope there is something new which I have missed. 
Maybe there is way to hook up the Tracking Service?

Comment: Windows and Windows Phone apps both support push notifications. Your example brings up all sorts of problems, but if your goal is timely notification via push then both platforms support it.

Both platforms have a geolocation api for tracking, but with the restrictions (that you mentioned) on background tasks they wouldn't trigger a timely notification.

Comment: I know that fact, but you app still needs to tell the server where the user/device is. So it needs to send trackinginfo in the background. Which is not possible on Windows 8.1 I think.

Comment: Correct. Currently on 8.1 there isn't support for running geolocation upon deactivation without resorting to background tasks, but it could arrive in the next release. Consider what this app would do to the battery, even if the platform wasn't restricting

Answer (score 0):

If the interaction works for you, you would want to create a windows phone app that supports running in the background much the way that GPS navigation applications work (the application must be navigating for it to run in the background).

[How to run location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Monitoring geolocation this way will be timely and you can create toast notifications, but you have to be wary of when the application will be deactivated. Whether the platform will work for you depends on your requirements and centers around deactivation. [Take a look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to see if the conditions for deactivation don't meet your standards, and implement a proof of concept.

Comment: So you suggest to develop a "Fake Navigation App" for getting "Real Time Tracking Information"? The Deactivation of the App is that kind of problem I think that doesn't meet the requirements. If there is no way to keep a app running or a background task running on Windows Phone 8 or Windows Store App then the whole environment is useless for my business case.
The Deactivation Reasons can't made safe to not happen, for example running 4 hours without user interaction is a thing that would happen often and the user would be in danger without getting warnings from the app. Thank you for the Links

Comment: I thought that might be the case, but didn't want to presume to know your requirements. I did a cross country bike trip and used some tracking apps that drained my battery in 4 or 5 hours even with the phone on standby. Then I couldn't use my phone, which is a big deal if there was an emergency